# Use event-time in beam pipeline when reading from Kafka source

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a beam pipeline that reads from a Kafka source (AppendLogTime is not available), timestamp is embedded in data objects in Kafka stream.

I want to use event-time for my pipeline, after googling a bit I see some solutions make use of CustomeFieldTimePolicy (extract timestamp of data objects and use it for setting watermark) when reading data from KafkaIO.

But then I see another solution, which is using WithTimestamps.of() to assign timestamp to elements.

My question is, what are the different between those 2 methods? Cause to me it seems they do very similar job.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `CustomFieldTimePolicy`. This will adjust the timestamps used to calculate the watermark of the Kafka source.

`WithTimestamps.of()` is used to alter the timestamps of elements in a pipeline, but does not affect watermarks. It is a [very simple transform](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/dd71c9ac472b62ff3598d3db47b0f26985bbc82a/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/WithTimestamps.java#L133) based on `ParDo`. It is limited in what transformations it can do, because it is forbidden to contradict the watermark.